# Add Glyphicons in Bootstrap project MVC 5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

This takes me days without sleep ... I can not visualize my glyphicons icons I am working under MVC 5 and Bootstrap 3 .... any help for me?

My View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />
        <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>

    <body>           

                <div class="col-md-6">

                        <div style="text-align:justify">
                            <h4><span class="glyphicon-tags"></span>ID Orden Compra: @TempData["IdOrden"]</h4>
                            <h4><span class="glyphicon-eye-open"></span>Proveedor: @TempData["NombreProveedor"]</h4>
                            <h4><span class="glyphicon-user"></span>Usuario: @TempData["NombreUsuario"] @TempData["ApellidoUsuario"]</h4>
                            <hr />
                        </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                         <input type = "submit" value="Guardar Recepcion" class="btn btn-info">                            
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

        }

     <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have `glyphicon` as the base css class and then you add the css classes for the specific one (`glyphicon-tags`) as the second css class

This should work

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags"></span>
```